# Intercept a file download in C# using either an http module or http handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, intercept

When downloading a file from an `ASP.NET / C#` web application running on IIS 7.5 server, how do you intercept a pdf file being downloaded within the response? The response has `Content-Type` of `application/pdf` and a `Content-Length` of `10091`.

Currently I have written a `HttpModule` that overrides methods:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context){
   context.BeginRequest+=Context_BeginRequest();
   context.EndRequest+=Context_EndRequest();

}

private void Begin_Request(Object sender, EventArgs e){
   // this function does not get called when downloading a file!
}


private void End_Request(Object sender, EventArgs e){
   // this function does not get called when downloading a file!
}
```

Which function do I need to override in order to intercept file download response?

The web.config looks like:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runallManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

    <add name="MyMod.Module" type="MyMod.Module"/>
</modules>

</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Have you registered the module?

Comment: Yes, the module is registered because both functions are invoked on normal web traffic (i.e. viewing a web page). But when I try to download a file is when neither function gets called.

Comment: I'm no expert at this level, but maybe requests for that file type, or all static files, don't go through the aspnet pipeline.

Comment: I added how my web.config looks like. There is no precondition like what @Jason mentioned.

Comment: Try adding it in IIS Manager (instead of web.config) by mapping *.pdf to your handler or module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show how you registered the module in your web.config, but if it looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="mymodule" type="typename, assemblyname" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Then you just need to remove the precondition attribute. Otherwise, your module won't be called for static files (and anything else that might not invoke the managed pipeline).

Comment: There is no preCondition.  I updated above what my web.config looks like

Comment: I hope you've solved this by now, but I suspect that I need more information about what you are doing. Generally, the method I outlined should work.

You could probably run the failed request tracing module to track down what IIS was actually doing.